# Multidimensional array is not working in task allocation

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here i have one array using this i have to make my expected array format,i have to array inside array i tried but i am not able make my expected array format, if anyone know means please update my answer

> print_r($productsArray)

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [allocation_date] => 2018-01-01
            [t_project] => 10001
            [t_assign_to] => G2E0357
            [t_start_time] => 01:30 PM
            [t_end_time] => 11:30 AM
            [allocated_day] => 2018-01-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [allocation_date] => 2018-01-02
            [t_project] => 10001
            [t_assign_to] => G2E0357
            [t_start_time] => 01:30 PM
            [t_end_time] => 11:30 AM
            [allocated_day] => 2018-01-02
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [allocation_date] => 2018-01-03
            [t_project] => 10001
            [t_assign_to] => G2E0357
            [t_start_time] => 01:30 PM
            [t_end_time] => 11:30 AM
            [allocated_day] => 2018-01-03
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [allocation_date] => 2018-01-18
            [t_project] => 10008
            [t_assign_to] => XPL0315
            [t_start_time] => 11:30 AM
            [t_end_time] => 07:30 PM
            [allocated_day] => 2018-01-18
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [allocation_date] => 2018-01-19
            [t_project] => 10008
            [t_assign_to] => XPL0315
            [t_start_time] => 11:30 AM
            [t_end_time] => 07:30 PM
            [allocated_day] => 2018-01-19
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [allocation_date] => 2018-01-20
            [t_project] => 10008
            [t_assign_to] => XPL0315
            [t_start_time] => 11:30 AM
            [t_end_time] => 07:30 PM
            [allocated_day] => 2018-01-20
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [allocation_date] => 2018-01-25
            [t_project] => 10008
            [t_assign_to] => G2E0357
            [t_start_time] => 10:30 AM
            [t_end_time] => 01:30 PM
            [allocated_day] => 2018-01-25
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [allocation_date] => 2018-01-26
            [t_project] => 10008
            [t_assign_to] => G2E0357
            [t_start_time] => 10:30 AM
            [t_end_time] => 01:30 PM
            [allocated_day] => 2018-01-26
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [allocation_date] => 2018-01-27
            [t_project] => 10008
            [t_assign_to] => G2E0357
            [t_start_time] => 10:30 AM
            [t_end_time] => 01:30 PM
            [allocated_day] => 2018-01-27
        )

)
```

> using above i have to make like this array (my expected results)

```
Array
(
    [G2E0357] => Array
        (
            [10001] => Array
              (
                [2018-01-01] => t_start_time (value should come here)
                [2018-01-02] => t_start_time (value should come here)
                [2018-01-03] => t_start_time (value should come here)
              )

              [10008] => Array
              (
                [2018-01-25] => t_start_time (value should come here)
                [2018-01-26] => t_start_time (value should come here)
                [2018-01-27] => t_start_time (value should come here)
              )
        )

    [XPL0315] => Array
        (
            [10001] => Array
              (
                [2018-01-18] => t_start_time (value should come here)
                [2018-01-19] => t_start_time (value should come here)
                [2018-01-20] => t_start_time (value should come here)
              )
        )

)
```

1. G2E0357 & XPL0315 (t_assign_to values)
2. 10001 & 10008 (t_project values)
3. 2018-01-25 (allocated_day values)

> I tried but i am not able to make my expected results

```
    $project_name = array();
foreach ($productsArray as $key => $value) {
    $project_name[$value['t_assign_to']][$value['allocated_day']]= $value['t_project'];
}
```

> print_r($project_name);

```
 Array
(
    [G2E0357] => Array
        (
            [2018-01-01] => 10001
            [2018-01-02] => 10001
            [2018-01-03] => 10001
            [2018-01-25] => 10008
            [2018-01-26] => 10008
            [2018-01-27] => 10008
        )

    [XPL0315] => Array
        (
            [2018-01-18] => 10008
            [2018-01-19] => 10008
            [2018-01-20] => 10008
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this code:

```
foreach($productsArray as $key0 => $info) {
    $key1 = $info['t_assign_to'];
    $key2 = $info['t_project'];
    $key3 = $info['allocated_day'];
    $project_name[$key1][$key2][$key3] = $info['t_start_time']; 
}
```

This is what I got with the code (incomplete):

```
array (
  'G2E0357' => 
  array (
    10001 => 
    array (
      '2018-01-01' => '01:30 PM',
      '2018-01-02' => '01:30 PM',
      '2018-01-03' => '01:30 PM',
    ),
    10008 => 
    array (
      '2018-01-25' => '10:30 AM',
    ),
  ),
  'XPL0315' => 
  array (
    10008 => 
    array (
      '2018-01-18' => '11:30 AM',
      '2018-01-19' => '11:30 AM',
      '2018-01-20' => '11:30 AM',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use your same code opposite way, try this

```
$project_name = array();
foreach ($productsArray as $key => $value) {
$project_name[$value['t_assign_to']]$value['t_project']]= array([$value['allocated_day']=> "t_start_time (value should come here)");
}
```